# Including CSS, jQuery, and HTML all into one .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking around, but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. I want to include both my jQuery and CSS into one .html page, but I cant seem to get the jQuery working. I'm not new to coding, but I am new to jQuery. Here's what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/b63nLkfa/1/

```
<div class=aboutMe>aboutMe</div>

<style>
    .bodyAmendment{
        width:100px;
    }
    .aboutMe{
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        height:250px;
        width:200px;
        color: white;
        font-size:32px;
    }
</style>

<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.aboutMe').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('bodyAmendment');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Obviously, I want to toggle classes when clicked (simply change the width of the div).

Comment: you most likely didn't include the jquery properly. I'd suggest google's hosted jquery include <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> into your html.

Comment: @wateriswet I've tried it a whole host of ways, including yours. Nothing seems to be working. I know the JQuery works, because when I use all 3 of JSFiddle's sheets, it works like it should. Thus, my only possible idea is that I didn't inplement Jquery properly, like you said.http://jsfiddle.net/8cgeejmt/

Comment: @Walker The reason why that fiddle works is because the CSS takes precedence in the proper order. If you had the order reversed, as long as the class `hi` was applied, all rules in `hi` would take precedence over any in `amend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't select jquery from jsfiddle sidebar. And remove

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
```

or use

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the new [link](http://jsfiddle.net/b63nLkfa/2/).

Comment: does this really merit being an answer? it's nothing more than a comment

Comment: Well use the second option instead and don't use jsfiddle since it won't work there. Stick the whole content into a html file and try to run it on a browser.

Comment: When I make a jsfiddle, it works. When I stick it into amy IDE, things dont work so well. http://jsfiddle.net/b63nLkfa/22/

Comment: Not working too well, but I'll tinker with it. Funny thing is, refreshing the page with this method takes a lot longer.

Comment: Try this [link](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9614001/). Copy the content into a html file and then run it.

Answer (score 1):

Both `aboutMe` and `bodyAmendment` have a width defined.  `toggleClass()` appends the class, so you wind up with `<div class="aboutMe bodyAmendment">`. `width: 200px` "wins" so it appears the code is doing nothing.  Try

```
.bodyAmendment{
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

or some other combo so you're not defining the same property in both classes.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/b63nLkfa/1/

```
.aboutMe{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    height:250px;
    width:200px;
    color: white;
    font-size:32px;
}
.bodyAmendment{
     width:100px;
}
```

Your problem is about css priorities. Let's check my fiddle and use tool like firebug. Always.

Comment: Ive told this to most other people. The coding is sound (for all I can see). The problem stems from the JQuery being included into HTML. I don't think I'm adding JQuery properly.

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to add in jQuery when you created your fiddle. This means your code was not firing. Also, when working with CSS, the last rule that is added takes precedence, regardless of when the class was added.

```
.test2 {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #F00;
}

.test1 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="test1">This is 200px</div>
<div class="test1 test2">This is also 200px!</div>
<div class="test2">This is 100px</div>
```

The CSS "cascades" down the document, each rule that comes later taking precedence over the last.

http://jsfiddle.net/b63nLkfa/21/

Answer (score -1):

I normally use .php, and use an

```
<? include "includes/js.php"; ?>
```

which in this one file I have all my script calls.  Make it alot easier to update an entire site from one file.

Comment: __O__ That's just classic.

Answer (score -2):

try `<div class="aboutMe">aboutMe</div>`

sometimes the  " " are important

Comment: They aren't important when the attribute value consists only of letters.

Comment: I dont think the punctuation is what's throwing it off. The code works fine, its just the implementation of JQuery into an HTML sheet.

Comment: if it's possible to use the latest version of jquery you can use this: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` i've tested it. then it works.

Comment: @TheKangaroo THIS WORKS! Any idea now how to find a similar link involving the JQuery UI?

Comment: I've searched for some linked includes, but couriusly they don't work. I would download the version and take the relative path.